# Why can't I place button in tk.Frame?

Tags: python, tkinter

So I was trying to make a tk.Frame program, but bumped into a problem.
I tried placing a button to an exact coordinate, but it wouldn't appear.
Here is a snippet of the program:

```
class Login(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.controller = controller
    button1 = Button(self, text="Login",padx=50,command=chech,background="grey",foreground="white")
    button2 = Button(self, text="SQLREG",padx=50,background="grey",foreground="white",command=lambda: controller.show_frame("Register"))
    button1.place(relx=228, rely=70)
    button2.place(relx=63, rely=70)
```

What should I do?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified a size for your frame so it's only going to be one pixel tall and wide. You're placing the button 228 times the width in the x direction and 63 times the height in the y direction, so it won't be visible.

As for a fix, it's hard to say without knowing what you're actually trying to do. My own personal advice is to not use `place`. When you use `pack` and `grid` tkinter will be able to make the frame large enough to hold all of its children. If you design your GUI with a logical layout rather than a fixed layout it will be much more responsive to changes in screen resolution, font sizes, and window sizes.